# Bash: Trying to get public IPv6 through a function

Tags: linux, bash, function

I am trying to see if my public IPv6 have anything in it, if not then output the text Unknown in a variable (for storage). Then have the variable shown later in a text eg: `echo "Public IPv6: "$PIP6` (variable that to save).

I know that I don't have a public IPv6 (it is slow to come in my country), so I would expect it to say Unknown.
But it is empty.

What seems to be the problem?

test.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
OS="$(uname)"
InternalIP=""
LIP="ip addr show"
LIP6="ip -6 addr show scope global"
IPv6=""
PIPv6=""

case $OS in
 *)InternalIP=$($LIP | grep 'inet'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk 'NF>0{print $2}');;
esac
case $OS in
 *)IPv6=$($LIP | grep 'inet6' | grep -v '128' | awk '{print $2}');;
esac
case $OS in
 *)PIPv6=$($LIP6 | grep 'inet6' | grep -v '128' | awk '{print $2}');;
esac
   if [ -z $PIPv6 ]; then
    echo $PIPv6
   else
    echo "Unknown"
   fi

length=$InternalIP
echo $InternalIP | awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-3)}'
echo $IPv6 | awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-3)}'
echo "Public IPv6: "$PIPv6
```

I tried different if styles. tried with `echo "Unknown` instead of result and then it showed up as Unknown, but I want it to save to a variable, not showing up at the beginning of the output:

```bash
Unknown
1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx
Public IPv6:
```

Now when I run the file: publicip.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
LIB="ip address show" # Show Network Information
PIB6="ip -6 adress show scope global" # Public IPv6

IPv4="$($LIB | awk '/inet/ && !/127/ && !/128/ && !/64/{print $2}')"
IPv6="$($LIB | awk '/inet6/ && !/128/{print $2}')"
PIPv4="$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"
PIPv6="$($PIP6 | awk '/inet6/ && !/128/{print $2}')"

if [ -z "$PIPv6" ]; then
  PIPv6="unknown"
fi

echo "Local IPv4: $IPv4" | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-3)}'
echo "Local IPv6: $IPv6" | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-3)}'
echo "Public IPv4: $PIPv4"
echo "Public IPv6: $PIPv6"
```

Output:

```bash
Local IPv4: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Local IPv6: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx
Public IPv4: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Public IPv6: Unknown
```

Just like I want it.

Comment: your test seems (a) backwards: `if [ -z $PIPv6 ]; then echo $PIPv6` seems to want to print the value when it is empty instead of when it is not empty, and (b) buggy - when `$PIPv6` **is** empty, because you didn't quote the variable, the test becomes `if [ -z ]; then echo $PIPv6` which still succeeds (because the string "-z" is not empty)

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you want the `PIPv6` variable to have the value `Unknown` if you don't find an IPv6 address.  The code doesn't work because it makes no attempt to change the value of the variable if it finds its value to be empty.  A simple fix for the problem is to replace `echo "Unknown"` with `PIPv6=Unknown`.  Another option is to use one of the techniques described in answers to the duplicate question that I've suggested.  One way to do it is to replace the `if [ -z $PIPv6 ] ... fi` with `: "${PIPv6:=Unknown}"`.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: pjh: It seems to be the same, but I can't understand that code or how it is formed. But thanks. And Thanks for the link to spellcheck. Didn't know about it. I am quite new to Bash-programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, untested:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

InternalIP=""
lip() { ip addr show; }
lip6() { ip -6 addr show scope global; }
IPv6=""
PIPv6=""

InternalIP=$(lip | awk -F':' '/inet/ && !/127\.0\.0\.1/ && split($2,a," ")>1{print a[2]}')
IPv6=$(lip | awk '/inet6/ && !/128/{print $2}')
PIPv6=$(lip6 | awk '/inet6/ && !/128/{print $2}')

if [[ -z $PIPv6 ]]; then
    PIPv6='Unknown'
fi

echo "$InternalIP" | awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-3)}'
echo "$IPv6" | awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-3)}'
echo "Public IPv6: $PIPv6"
```

I don't understand some of your code and you didn't provide the output of your 2 `ip` commands so I don't know why you're using the commands you are on it so the above is just a translation of your code into what I think you wanted it to do.

The most significant change is probably that I think you wanted to set PIPv6 to `Unknown` when it's empty, not just print a blank line.

Comment: I have tried what you wrote. awk for InternalIP will not work when I try it in the terminal (lLinux), it comes out empty.

Comment: @Cordux As I mentioned, I'm just guessing at what you need since you didn't show us the output of your `ip` commands. Whatever is wrong in the awk script will be trivial to correct if you edit your question to show that information.

Comment: If you look at the question again, you will see the whole file. I got it to work.

Comment: You show your whole script but not the one thing we really need to help you which is the output of the 2 commands you're trying to parse the output of - `ip addr show` and `ip -6 addr show scope global`. "got it to work" is relative. You're doing a few things that don't make sense, e.g. those case statements, some that are buggy, e.g. not escaping `.`s in your regexp, and some that are well known anti-patterns, e.g. storing code in variables, this could be a good opportunity for you to learn a bit more about bash programming.

Comment: ip addr show is the command to show network-informtion on almost any version of Linux (I think).
So each is taking that information and then grep what I need (the word inet in the first, then reverse (-v) and remove that one with localhost-ip(127.0.0.01),) Cut takes away the first and third row (at least what I know), then NF>0 takes away the empty rows after, and then only writes out with awk. (That is my understanding of it.)

Comment: I don't currently have Linux and I don't have the `ip` command, but that's irrelevant - if you edit your question to show the output that YOU get from those commands then we can help you. I know what the commands you are using do, and I've shown what I believe to be the awk equivalent of each command pipeline, but if it's not producing the output you expect then maybe I got something wrong but I won't know til I see the text you're trying to parse. By seeing the output I can probably suggest a more robust way of parsing it too as matching a regexp across the whole of each line is fragile.

Comment: And we can definitely get rid of the 2 extra calls to awk at the end of your script once we know what the input looks like. (I'm saying "we" as many people posting here can help you once you provide the missing input, not just me).

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work: When you're checking if `PIPv6` is empty and attempting to echo "Unknown" if it's not set, your script logic is inverted. You echo `$PIPv6` when it's empty (which will just print nothing since `PIPv6` is empty) and print "Unknown" when it's not empty, which is the opposite of what you're aiming for.

Additionally, you want to store the "Unknown" value in the `PIPv6` variable if no IPv6 is found, not just echo it. Here's a revised version of your script with the corrected logic and variable assignment:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
OS="$(uname)"
InternalIP=""
LIP="ip addr show"
LIP6="ip -6 addr show scope global"
IPv6=""
PIPv6=""

case $OS in
 *)InternalIP=$($LIP | grep 'inet'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk 'NF>0{print $2}');;
esac
case $OS in
 *)IPv6=$($LIP | grep 'inet6' | grep -v '128' | awk '{print $2}');;
esac
case $OS in
 *)PIPv6=$($LIP6 | grep 'inet6' | grep -v '128' | awk '{print $2}');;
esac

# Check if PIPv6 is empty and set to "Unknown" if it is
if [ -z "$PIPv6" ]; then
    PIPv6="Unknown"
fi

length=$InternalIP
echo $InternalIP | awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-3)}'
echo $IPv6 | awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-3)}'
echo "Public IPv6: "$PIPv6
```

Now, the script will correctly output "Unknown" for the public IPv6 address if none is found, and store this in the `PIPv6` variable for later use, as you intended. Please make other changes accordingly.

Comment: I pointed that out and included the fix for it and a few other things in my answer posted an hour earlier.